# Local out of date git

Tags: git, github, git-remote

When I run git remote show origin on terminal, it shows the following - 
Local out of date. How can one update it?
I think that this is the probable reason why I am not able to push changes to the repository.

```js
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/tono/emotion-detection.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/tono/emotion-detection.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    master tracked
    tono tracked
    boro tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    master  pushes to master  (local out of date)
    boro pushes to boro (local out of date)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/292357/1256452 - but note that beginners should avoid `git pull` entirely, and use only `git fetch` followed by manually running the second step, which often should be `git rebase` rather than `git merge`. By doing this as two separate commands, instead of the convenience `git pull`, you will be able to understand much better what Git is doing: the `fetch` *obtains* the items and the merge-or-rebase *integrates* the items.

Comment: Neither the comment or the answers to alleged duplicate gives any useful explanation of what the output from git remote means.