# What does git remote mean when it says local refs are out of date

Tags: git

I'm confused by what I see when I do the following:

```
git clone git@github.com:RobArthan/pp pp-xxx
cd pp-xxx
git branch sieve
git remote show origin
```

The output I get is:

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@github.com:RobArthan/pp
  Push  URL: git@github.com:RobArthan/pp
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    fix-3.1w6    tracked
    fix-3.1w7    tracked
    master       tracked
    pp_file_conv tracked
    sieve        tracked
    utf8         tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
    sieve  pushes to sieve  (local out of date)
```

As I have only just taken the clone, what can be out of date and why? A [question showing a similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42074748/local-out-of-date-git) was dismissed as a duplicate, but the cited questions don't actually explain what the `git remote` output means.

Comment: I think you created a local branch by using 'branch' command rather than a checkout. Could you try 'git checkout sieve' after cloning ?

Comment: @zatta: Many thanks, that explains it. Stupidity on my part!

Comment: Cool! Glad helped. Just added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a local branch instead of checking out it, that is the reason git is comparing and saying it is out of date. Just type `git checkout sieve` after cloning and that should resolve it.